# Как "разбить" число на сумму чисел?

Tags: python, числа

Например, есть число **3894**

Как его вывести в print таким образом:

```
1000
1000
1000
500
100
100
100
50
10
10
10
10
1
1
1
1
```

Числа такие: 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000

Comment: Сумму каких чисел? У вас то 1000, то 100, то 50, то 10

Comment: 1,
     5,
     10,
     50,
     100,
     500,
     1000

Comment: Почему тогда идет 8 раз по 100, а не 500 и 3 раза по 100?

Comment: И я так понимаю - если миллион, то его надо тысячами дробить?

Comment: Ой, моя  ошибка. Да, должно быть 500 и 3 раза 100. Да, если миллион, то по 1000

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос свои попытки решения данной задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, это не самое элегантное решение, но в принципе можно "в лоб" написать простенькую функцию, которая будет дробить число, пока это возможно:

```
def divide_number(number: int, numbers_to_divide: list) -> list:
    if number <= 0:
        return [number]
    divide_numbers = []
    for divide_number in numbers_to_divide:
        while number >= divide_number:
            number -= divide_number
            divide_numbers.append(divide_number)
    return divide_numbers


number = 3894
numbers_to_divide = [1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1]

result = divide_number(number, numbers_to_divide)
print(*result, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 1000
> 1000
> 1000
> 500
> 100
> 100
> 100
> 50
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 1
> 1
> 1
> ```